# Joomla Buttons Conflicting Each Other

Tags: javascript, php, html, button, joomla

I have two modules which each contain a button code as follows:

First Button

```
<div onclick="parent.location='first-link'" data-mce-onclick=""><button class="button">First Button</button>
```

Second Button

```
<div onclick="parent.location='second-link'" data-mce-onclick=""><button class="button">Second Button</button>
```

When I show these buttons in the same template position on at the same time in the article, the `First Button` loses it’s functionality.  What do I need to change in order to have them both be able to function properly within the same page?

Comment: Close the `<div>`? I.e. `<div onclick="parent.location='first-link'" data-mce-onclick=""><button class="button">First Button</button></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use 1 module only for your links and
use css place your buttons
check this site for how to it uses 1 module for placing that links
http://soroushabtahi.com

Comment: Thanks!  That is interesting, why would the separate modules compete with each other?